# 'this' context in Meteor event is empty object

Tags: meteor

Template works fine (in terms of data being displayed), but event doesn't. Particularly odd because I have a different template with almost the identical code in which it works.

```
<template name="profile_sidebar">
    {{#if opened}}
        {{> profile_sidebar_contents}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="profile_sidebar_contents">
    {{#if dataReady}}
        {{#unless equalsCurrentUsername profile.login}}
           <span>
             <a class="message-user"><i class="ion-chatbox"></i> Message</a>
           </span>
        {{/unless}}
   {{/if}}
</template>

Template.profile_sidebar_contents.events({
    'click .message-user': function(e,t){
        // this is {}
        // t.data is null
        Session.set('selectedConversation', this._id);
        Router.go('/messages');
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried explicitly using the `{{#with data}} ... {{/with}}` block?

Comment: That worked when I swapped it to {{#with profile}} .. {{/with}} but I really wanted the parent context. essentially I want {{#with .}} {{/with}}

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

I wrapped the entire template in a {{#with profile}} ... {{/with}} block and then added the data I needed to be within the profile object returned in the helper. It seems as though the context of the event was empty object because the event target was not within a scope.

**Elaborated below**

I assumed that the context would default to an object which had as fields all helpers. Ex. I had

```
Template.profile_sidebar_contents.helpers({
   profile: function(){ return something },
   id: function() {return somethingelse }
});
```

and I expected the context of this to be {profile: something, id: somethingelse}
but it seems that this isn't done and the context is empty. I moved it to be

```
Template.profile_sidebar_contents.helpers({
       profile: function(){ return {profile:something, id:somethingelse} }
});
```

and then set {{#with profile}} ... {{/with}} and had access to the profile helper returned object, by which I could retrieve id by this.id and profile by this.profile

Comment: What did you change exactly? This answer is not exactly precise and/or useful to the people of the future.